# Access violation in winforms when adding items to CheckedListBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

When I try to add several items to a CheckedListBox via code in the following way:

```
foreach (enumValue in Enum.GetValues(typeof(SomeEnum)))
{
    myCheckedListBox.Items.Add(enumValue, true);
}
```

I get an access violation exception with the stack trace:

```
System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
at System.Drawing.SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdipDrawRectangleI(HandleRef graphics, HandleRef pen, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height)
at System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pen pen, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height)
at System.Windows.Forms.ControlPaint.DrawFlatCheckBox(Graphics graphics, Rectangle rectangle, Color foreground, Brush background, ButtonState state)
at System.Windows.Forms.ControlPaint.DrawFlatCheckBox(Graphics graphics, Rectangle rectangle, ButtonState state)
at System.Windows.Forms.ControlPaint.DrawCheckBox(Graphics graphics, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, ButtonState state)
at System.Windows.Forms.ControlPaint.DrawCheckBox(Graphics graphics, Rectangle rectangle, ButtonState state)
at System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox.OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.WmReflectDrawItem(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

I have had those a lot in my current project. I got them for multiple things like DataGridView or BackgroundImage. In the case of DataGridView i subclassed it and set the "DoubleBuffered" property to "true". I found this solution [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/89534844-b261-43dd-823b-8d443235082e/pretty-often-systemaccessviolationexception).

But this does not work for the CheckedListBox case.

I guess that there is probably something wrong with the system in general but the application is supposed to run on this specific type of hardware (Win XP embedded, Atom CPU, 1GB of RAM) which is already in use several hundred times and I am not allowed to patch it (e.g. updating .NET). It happens on all instances of this hardware but not on other hardware.

I have no unmanaged code that I call explicitly, which is something that is suggested in similar threads that I have found.

I also tried calling the item-adding code after the form is already fully loaded (e.g. by calling it via a button that i added for debugging purpose).

The same happens when I do not add the items via the enum-iteration but just call it manually like

```
myCheckedListBox.Items.Add("SomeString", true);
```

If I do not add the items (just leave the CheckedListBox empty), the access violation does not occur.

Comment: Seems like a bug in the underlying system. Perhaps you could try working around it by putting all the objects to add into an object array first, and then call `Items.AddRange()` to add them all at once. You could also try calling `ListBox.BeginUpdate()` before adding the items, and call `ListBox.EndUpdate()` afterwards. You should always do that if you're adding more than a handful of items.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but this did sadly not cause the issue to disappear.